# How to Redirect one application to another application using Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

I have two Asp.net Applications, first one application aspx page have  Iframe , when page load redirect Another application aspx page (based on port location in iss) , Iframe bellow page have link button , when i have to click that button redirect first application (main Application) but now with in the iframe display the First application page , how to redirect the main application.

```
    Code
    ------------
   (82) Main Application:(first)(192.***.*.***:82/Rate.aspx)-->This Application have Two pages Rate.aspx, Default.aspx.
    -----------------
 Click -->  (82) Rate.aspx:(have one Iframe)

Page Load() method to load the another application Default.aspx page like    
     ifrm.Attributes["src"] ="http://192.***.*.***:83/default.aspx";

  Second Appliction --> (83) Default page : have one button , button click  event fired to redirect Main Application (82) default page have to display. code
    -----------------
    protected void lblWWPremiumRate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Response.Redirect("http://192.***.*.***:82/default.aspx");         

            }
```

Comment: could you explain this in more detail? are you trying to redirect one iframe from another iframe?

Comment: No only one Iframe, redirect to another page. pls see the changes

Comment: Pls make your code more readable.